# Pandas : How to replace values in a range with a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace values in a certain range with some other value.

I have a dictionary containing a char as key and the upper range as a value like the following -

```
replace_dict = {
        'A': 10, 
        'B': 21, 
        'C': 34, 
        'D': 49, 
        'E': 66, 
        'F': 85, 
        'G': 107, 
        'H': 132, 
        'I': 160, 
        'J': 192, 
        'K': 229, 
        'L': 271, 
        'M': 319, 
        'N': 395, 
        'O': 495, 
        'P': 595, 
        'Q': 795, 
        'R': 1100
}
```

I need to replace the values with the corresponding keys that fall in a range.

**For example:**

```
Values in the range of 1-10 will be replaced by 'A',
Values in the range of 11-21 will be replaced by 'B'
Values in the range of 22-34 will be replaced by 'C'
Values in the range of 35-50 will be replaced by 'D'
Values in the range of 51-66 will be replaced by 'E'
```

I've written the following code:

```
k=1
for i, j in replace_dict.items():
    data.loc[data['my_col'].between(k,j)] = i
    k=j+1
```

This code shows `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`.

However, the line `data.loc[data['my_col'].between(1,10)] = 'A'` works fine.

What is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: just invert i and j

Comment: Is `data['my_col']`'s dtype `str`?  Try `data['my_col'],astype('int32').between(k,j)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html). A few points to note:

1. We use the fact ordering of `dict.keys` and `dict.values` is consistent.
2. We provide `bins` and `labels` explicitly; note that `labels` must have one less item than `bins`.
3. You may wish to add an extra bin for values above 1100.

Here is a minimal example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [500, 123, 56, 12, 1000, 2, 456]})

df['mapped'] = pd.cut(df['col'],
                      bins=[1]+list(replace_dict.values()),
                      labels=list(replace_dict.keys()))

print(df)

    col mapped
0   500      P
1   123      H
2    56      E
3    12      B
4  1000      R
5     2      A
6   456      O
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate DataFrame using your desired ranges and `map` using an `intervalIndex`

***Setup***

```
ranges = pd.DataFrame(replace_dict, index=['STOP']).T.reset_index()
ranges['START'] = (ranges.STOP.shift(1)+1).fillna(1)
ranges.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(ranges.START, ranges.STOP, closed='both')

                index  STOP  START
[1.0, 10.0]         A    10    1.0
[11.0, 21.0]        B    21   11.0
[22.0, 34.0]        C    34   22.0
[35.0, 49.0]        D    49   35.0
[50.0, 66.0]        E    66   50.0
etc...
```

**`map`** using your **`intervalIndex`**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nums': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 10)})
   nums
0   699
1   133
2   829
3   299
4   306
5   691
6   172
7   225
8   522
9   671

df.nums.map(ranges['index'])

0    Q
1    I
2    R
3    M
4    M
5    Q
6    J
7    K
8    P
9    Q
```